# Cucumber book w/ github repo for Ruby 2 + Rails 4 + Rspec 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'm working through Aaron Sumner's Rspec book and he doesn't like Cucumber so there's only instructions for Capybara. While I agree that Capybara is superior, my project unfortunately uses Cucumber, so that's what I need to master.

Can someone please point me at a current resource like this for Cucumber? Everything comparable I found was old.

By "resource like this" I mean an ebook (or other text-based tutorial that does not require a subscription) with a Github repo. I'm happy to pay for  one, so long as it's reasonably priced.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is simply an abstraction layer for your tests. If you like Capybara, you can easily use it with Cucumber.

I would recommend starting with the Capybara repo https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber

Comment: Yes, but this is a shared project and I don't get to choose the technology. I need to learn cucumber, and I want a well-designed tutorial like the rspec book.